# Sum Two Pandas Group By Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, pandas-groupby

I have two pandas group by objects and I want to sum their values. I am not able to figure out the how to merge these two data frames so that column `CALL_BLOCK` have all the ten call blocks for that `DOW` and also sum the values. I tried several approaches like resetting the index and merging the two data frames but still, I am not able to get all the ten call blocks for column `CALL_BLOCKS`. I'll appreciate your help. Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDITED**

```
df1 = {('1-100019B', 'a_8:00AM to 9:00AM'): 0.6493506493506493,
 ('1-100019B', 'b_9:00AM to 10:00AM'): 0.7272727272727273,
 ('1-100019B', 'c_10:00AM to 11:00AM'): 0.16883116883116883,
 ('1-100019B', 'd_11:00AM to 12:00PM'): 0.025974025974025976,
 ('1-100019B', 'e_12:00PM to 1:00PM'): 0.38961038961038963,
 ('1-100019B', 'f_1:00PM to 2:00PM'): 0.14285714285714285,
 ('1-100019B', 'g_2:00PM to 3:00PM'): 0.0,
 ('1-100019B', 'h_3:00PM to 4:00PM'): 0.12987012987012986,
 ('1-100019B', 'i_4:00PM to 5:00PM'): 0.0,
 ('1-100019B', 'j_After 5PM'): 0.0}

df2 = 
{('1-100019B', 0, 'a_8:00AM to 9:00AM'): 0.5,
 ('1-100019B', 0, 'b_9:00AM to 10:00AM'): 0.6666666666666666,
 ('1-100019B', 0, 'c_10:00AM to 11:00AM'): 0.25,
 ('1-100019B', 0, 'e_12:00PM to 1:00PM'): 0.3333333333333333,
 ('1-100019B', 0, 'f_1:00PM to 2:00PM'): 0.0,
 ('1-100019B', 0, 'h_3:00PM to 4:00PM'): 1.0}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
df = 
CONTACT_ID  DOW  CALL_BLOCKS         
1-100019B   0    a_8:00AM to 9:00AM      1.149
                 b_9:00AM to 10:00AM     1.380
                 c_10:00AM to 11:00AM    0.410
                 d_11:00AM to 12:00PM    0.026
                 e_12:00PM to 1:00PM     0.710
                 f_1:00PM to 2:00PM      0.140
                 g_2:00PM to 3:00PM      0.000
                 h_3:00PM to 4:00PM      1.120
                 i_4:00PM to 5:00PM      0.000
                 j_After 5PM             0.000
```

Comment: Can you add df1.to_dict() and df2.to_dict() to this question.

Comment: Hi Scott, Edited. Is this helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @jpp setup,

```
df1.merge(df2.reset_index('DOW'), on=['CONTACTS_ID','CALL_BLOCKS'], how='outer')\
   .set_index('DOW', append=True).sum(1)
```

Output:

```
CONTACTS_ID  CALL_BLOCKS           DOW
1-100019B    a_8:00AM to 9:00AM    0.0    1.149351
             b_9:00AM to 10:00AM   0.0    1.393939
             c_10:00AM to 11:00AM  0.0    0.418831
             d_11:00AM to 12:00PM  NaN    0.025974
             e_12:00PM to 1:00PM   0.0    0.722944
             f_1:00PM to 2:00PM    0.0    0.142857
             g_2:00PM to 3:00PM    NaN    0.000000
             h_3:00PM to 4:00PM    0.0    1.129870
             i_4:00PM to 5:00PM    NaN    0.000000
             j_After 5PM           NaN    0.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This helps. Thank you.

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal I am glad this helped.  You're welcome.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Drop the unused `MultiIndex` level from your second dataframe, and then use `pd.Series.add`:

```
df2.index = df2.index.droplevel(1)

res = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)

print(res)

                                0
idx1      idx3                          
1-100019B a_8:00AM to 9:00AM    1.149351
          b_9:00AM to 10:00AM   1.393939
          c_10:00AM to 11:00AM  0.418831
          d_11:00AM to 12:00PM  0.025974
          e_12:00PM to 1:00PM   0.722944
          f_1:00PM to 2:00PM    0.142857
          g_2:00PM to 3:00PM    0.000000
          h_3:00PM to 4:00PM    1.129870
          i_4:00PM to 5:00PM    0.000000
          j_After 5PM           0.000000
```

**Setup**

This is the code I used to get from your input dictionaries to `MultiIndex` series, which is what you would see as output of `groupby` operations.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df1, orient='index').reset_index()
df1 = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(df1['index'].values.tolist(), columns=['idx1', 'idx3'])).drop('index', 1)
df1 = df1.set_index(['idx1', 'idx3'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df2, orient='index').reset_index()
df2 = df2.join(pd.DataFrame(df2['index'].values.tolist(), columns=['idx1', 'idx2', 'idx3'])).drop('index', 1)
df2 = df2.set_index(['idx1', 'idx2', 'idx3'])
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I can't drop `level=1 (DOW)` because I want the values specific to `DOW` column similar to what I have described under the expected output.

Comment: Will it be simpler to use `reset_index()` on these group by objects to convert them to the pandas data frame and work off them and in that case the output would be a data frame in described format?